# Ajax.BeginForm with MVC is not going to my action

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a problem with using an Ajax form in MVC.  Out of no where I am getting the following error:

POST http://localhost:50778/Evaluation/Setup/[object%20NodeList] 404 (Not Found)

It seems to not be adding the action or calling any simple validation.  On oter pages it seems to work.  i have stripped everything down the the basics below and it still doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Edited: As a workaround i'm using jquery to submit the form but i really don't think i need to be doing that.

```
<div id="form-message"></div>
@{Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateEvaluation", "Setup", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "form-message", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}, new { @id = "evaluation-setup" });}

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.fk_baa)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.lock_setup)


<div class="form-actions">
    <p><b>Note</b>: There is no spell check on this site. You may wish to create text in Word or another word processor and then copy-and-paste into the system. </p>
    <button name="action" type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button id="apply-lock" name="action" type="submit" class="btn btn-success exempt" value="lock"><span class="ico fa"></span> Lock Setup</button>
</div>

@{Html.EndForm();}
```

Here is my action

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateEvaluation(SetupEvaluationModel model, string action)
    {
        var valid = ModelState.IsValid;
        if (action.ToUpper().Equals("LOCK"))
        {
            return View("_Validation", model.Save(true));
        }
        else
        {

            return View("_Validation", model.Save());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I updated my button to this input and the error changed a bit. http://localhost:50778/Evaluation/Setup/[object%20HTMLInputElement] 404 (Not Found) looks like it is adding the input element to the url and removing the action.

Comment: You should wrap everything in @using(Ajax.BeginForm(){}) and remove the @{Html.EndForm();}

Comment: can you maybe provide your actions and the model  being used?

Comment: @afzalulh I tried that and it didn't work either. I will post my action and model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename `String action` to a different name in your action signature. You'll have to rename your button names as well. With the code you have now the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js submit handler is trying to route to a button object instead of the correct string url route.

Comment: You sir are a genius!!! That was the problem.  I have used "action" as the name of a button before but it was on a regular form and not ajax one.  I spent hours on this !!!!!